# In a do-catch statement, will execution stop inside "do" as soon as one "try" throws an error or will everything be attempted?

Tags: swift, swift2, try-catch

For example:

```
do {
    try throwableFunction()
    try anotherThrowableFunction()
    nonThrowingFunction()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Will `nonThrowingFunction()` always execute even if one of the first `try` statements throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a throwing function actually throws an error, it will resume with the catch block.

In your example: if `throwableFunction()` actually throws, the other statements will not be executed but the program will continue with the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, execution stops on the first failure. Otherwise the code is in an invalid state. Think about a case where an optional was returned nil, how would you proceed with accessing its properties?  If you need to handle different try statements in unique ways, then you will either need multiple do/catch scopes or multiple catch tests.